# is there any function in jpa to find customer by its firstName

Tags: java, spring, spring-boot, jpa, spring-data

I want to fetch the record from the database by using JPA base in built query I want to fetch the customer by its first Name so is there any method like below example available?

Customer findByfirst-name(String name); // I tried it

but not found the best solutions I want to get the response as per FirstName of Customer

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You may define a method in your repository interface with a particular naming convention to find a customer by their first name using Spring Data JPA. Here's an example of how to do this, assuming you have an entity class named Customer with a field called firstName:

```
Customer findByFirstName(String firstName);
```

Comment: it's really worked for me and thanks for your kind response I was stuck from the last 2 to 3 days Thanks a lot sir for this guidance.